# TypeError: this.<class>.<function> is not a function

Tags: angular, typescript

I have this component

```
export class Component1Component implements OnInit {

public greetings: string ="";

constructor(private greeter: Greeter) { }

ngOnInit() {
   this.greetings =  this.greeter.sayHello();
}

}
```

Greeter class is defined as

```
export class Greeter{ 
  private hello_greetings = "Hello";
  constructor(){} 
  public sayHello():string {
    return this.hello_grittings;
  }
 }
```

The Greeter class is provided by a factory:

```
export function GreeterFactory():Greeter { return new Greeter(); }

@NgModule({
    providers: [                               
        { provide: Greeter,          
          useFactory: GreeterFactory,
          multi: true                       
        }
  ]
})
```

When Component1 is loaded, I get this error:

> AppComponent.html:1 ERROR TypeError: this.greeter.sayHello is not a
>   function
>       at Component1Component.ngOnInit (component1.component.ts:36)

If I print this.greeter in the OnInit method, I get this output:

> [{"hello_greetings":"Hello"}]

So, it looks like the class is being injected correctly, but for some reason the methods are not been found at run time.

The Whole project can be found [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-mwue9p)

Thanks in advance for your help

Answer (score 1):

You need to remove `multi: true` from the provider. This flag indicates that the object will be injected as a an array. This is exactly what you see in your console output: `[{"hello_greetings":"Hello"}]` (notice the `[]`).

Comment: Silly mistake! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You're providing your `Greeter` service with the option `multiple: true`, therefore multiple instances of the service are allowed and angular injects them as an array of instances.

You have to change `multi: true` to `multi: false` or omit it.

Answer (score 0):

This happens because `greeter` is an array of `Greeter` instances, in order for types to be correct it should be injected like

```
constructor(@Inject(Greeter) private greeter: Greeter[]) { }
```

As [the reference](https://angular.io/api/core/FactoryProvider#multi) states,

> multi?: boolean
>
> If true, then injector returns an array of instances. This is useful
>   to allow multiple providers spread across many files to provide
>   configuration information to a common token.

If it is supposed to be multi-provider then the method should be called on one of the instances, `this.greeter[0].sayHello()`. If it isn't then no `multi`  should be specified.